# Nginx - Set Up Multiple SSL Certificates on One IP different ports - no SNI

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have a requirement to set up multiple SSL certificates on one IP but I am not allowed to use SNI(client not support it). Is it possible to do it with same server name but different ports?

Comment: Consider using a single certificate which contains all of the necessary hostnames. This eliminates the need to use nonstandard port numbers. Also be aware that obsolete clients that don't support SNI might not support modern SSL certificates with SHA2 signatures either. Windows XP comes to mind. These things should be removed from the Internet ASAP.

Comment: With Let's Encrypt you can easily have a multiple-hostname certificate for free.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, but only one certificate would be available on the default https port 443... The clients will need to be instructed to connect to the correct alternate port. I.e. the client would need to connect to `https://www.example.org:445`

```
server {
    listen          443 ssl;
    server_name     www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate www.example.com.crt;
    ...
}
server {
    listen          444 ssl;
    server_name     www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate www.example.com.444.crt;
    ...
}
server {
    listen          445 ssl;
    server_name     www.example.org;
    ssl_certificate www.example.org.crt;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this works for me as well. @Ilay, what problems were you seeing?

Comment: Keep in mind that some places block port 445 to frustrate file sharing attacks (and file sharing) over the Internet.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes indeed, running web services on non-standard ports might have sub optimal results and using the default port of another well-known service even more so....

Comment: Thanks this is working! for some reason in port 6647 it didn't work for me, but in other ports it is works!

Comment: 6647 is probably IRC, and blocked as such by a firewall for the same reasons as above.